# Can't Set MongoDB Document Field to Null

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I am attempting to modify a collection via the mongo shell to trim all strings, then, if the field is a string but is numeric, change its data type to a number.

Here is the code I am using:

```
function isNumeric(num) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(num)) && isFinite(num);
}

var bulk = db.yale.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
var counter = 0;
db.yale.find().forEach((doc) => {

    let updoc = {
        "$set" : {}
    };

    // get document fields but ignore immutable id field
    let fields = Object.keys(doc);
    let badField = fields.indexOf("_id");
    if (badField > -1) {
        fields.splice(badField, 1);
    }

    fields.forEach((field) => {
        if (typeof doc[field] === "string") {
            updoc["$set"][field] = doc[field].trim();
        }
    });

    fields.forEach((field) => {
        if (typeof doc[field] === "string") {
            if (isNumeric(doc[field])) {
                updoc["$set"][field] = parseFloat(doc[field]);
            } else {
                if (doc[field].length === 0) {
                    updoc["$set"][field] = null;
                }
            }
        }
    });

    bulk.find({
        "_id" : doc._id
    }).update(updoc);
    counter++;
    if (counter % 1000 === 0) {
        bulk.execute();
        bulk = db.yale.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
    }
});
```

(Note 1: the dataset is the Yale Bright Star catalog from the Vizier service, hence the name).
(Note 2: I prefer a `isNumeric()` function to `!isNan()` because I honestly think it looks better, personal preference)

Before the code is run, the first couple of results from `db.yale.find()` looks like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d945e8baea250effd9dd0dc"), "HR" : "   1", "Name" : "          ", "HD" : "     3", "SAO" : " 36042", "ADS" : "   46", "VarID" : "         ", "RAJ2000" : "00 05 09.9", "DEJ2000" : "+45 13 45", "Vmag" : " 6.70", "BV" : " 0.07", "SpType" : "  A1Vn              ", "NoteFlag" : "" }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d945e8baea250effd9dd0dd"), "HR" : "  11", "Name" : "          ", "HD" : "   315", "SAO" : 128595, "ADS" : "     ", "VarID" : "Var?     ", "RAJ2000" : "00 07 44.1", "DEJ2000" : "-02 32 56", "Vmag" : " 6.43", "BV" : -0.14, "SpType" : "  B8IIIpSi          ", "NoteFlag" : "*" }
```

After the run, the first lines look like this:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d945e8baea250effd9dd0dc"), "HR" : 1, "Name" : "", "HD" : 3, "SAO" : 36042, "ADS" : 46, "VarID" : "", "RAJ2000" : "00 05 09.9", "DEJ2000" : "+45 13 45", "Vmag" : 6.7, "BV" : 0.07, "SpType" : "A1Vn", "NoteFlag" : null }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d945e8baea250effd9dd0dd"), "HR" : 11, "Name" : "", "HD" : 315, "SAO" : 128595, "ADS" : "", "VarID" : "Var?", "RAJ2000" : "00 07 44.1", "DEJ2000" : "-02 32 56", "Vmag" : 6.43, "BV" : -0.14, "SpType" : "B8IIIpSi", "NoteFlag" : "*" }
```

Notice that in the first Document, the "ADS" field has been converted to a number, but in the second Document, the "ADS" field is still an empty string, empty though it should have been converted to null.

I do not want to remove the field from the collection entirely. For the sake of the service that will be using it, the value of null means something.

Can anyone see an issue with the javascript that is causing the field not to convert to null? It's probably just a dumb error I am overlooking.

Jason

Comment: Can you try passing `undefined` rather than `null` ? Would that work?

Comment: *"...the "ADS" field is still an empty string, empty though it should have been converted to null."* -- Um **No**. Read your code again. *Yes*, you actually did do `updoc["$set"][field] = doc[field].trim();` but **at no stage** did you actually do `doc[field] = doc[field].trim()`. Which of course is what the rest of your logic actually expected you to do, since `doc[field].length === 0` is not **zero** of course since you never actually changed **that variable**, and only changed the value in the database. Nothing to do with MongoDB at all. You just did not implement the logic incorrectly.

Comment: Also, it's not really great practice to use the `bulk` API methods *directly*. You really *should* be using `bulkWrite()` instead. That method does in fact gracefully downgrade in the event you actually connect to a MongoDB which does not support bulk operations. Not that you should be connecting to such an old MongoDB in this day of age, nor would it really matter that much for a "single shot" conversion operation. But you also should be aware of the better practice.

Comment: BTW. Dud edit. *"...did not implement the logic **correctly**"*. Not *incorrectly* as I somehow managed to edit before the 5 min window for comment edits were up. See how important it is to review things properly now? - The pot

Comment: @Neil Lunn yup, I suspected I did something stupid. I'm also going to look at making all of the changes to the doc in one shot, and using ``Bulk.replaceOne()``` to decrease the number of total operations.

Database version is not a problem, Mongo is running from a very recent Docker image.

Comment: I will look into ```bulkWrite()``` as I'm still getting used to the api.

Comment: Okay, based on the docs, I see how to use replaceOne() with bulkWrite(), thanks for pointing me in that direction.